# Service bus one subscriber for multiple dead-letter topic subscribers

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Is it possible for topics to have one subscriber for dead letters which themselves are being generated from multiple subscribers themselves?

E.g. two subscribers to a topic, sub-a and sub-b, if either of them generate a dead-letter, a subscriber "sub-deadletter" should pick it up. Is this possible?

The context of all of this is an C# azure function

Comment: Try to use the ServiceBusExplorer tool for configuring a ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo property to the same entity either the queue or topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptiondescription.forwarddeadletteredmessagesto?view=azure-dotnet) property of the topic Subscriptions and topic subscription [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) to bring you required functionality.

> 1.You need to set the ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo property of each topic subscription to the same Service Bus Topic to which the topic subscriptions belong.
>
> 2.Create a Topic Subscription rule for the topic subscription that should process your dead-lettered messages, with a correlation filter to receive only the dead-lettered messages.

A combination of both these features of Azure service Bus Topic Subscriptions should solve your problem.